# Closed form for summation involving ceil function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $n, m$ be integers. $m > 1, n > m$.

$$S = \left\lceil{\frac{n}{m}}\right\rceil + \left\lceil{\frac{1}{m}\left\lceil{\frac{n}{m}}\right\rceil}\right\rceil + \left\lceil{\frac{1}{m}}\left\lceil{\frac{1}{m}\left\lceil{\frac{n}{m}}\right\rceil}\right\rceil\right\rceil + \cdots + 1$$

Is there a closed form possible for S? I know a code for this is *very* easy, but I'm more interested in the "formula" than the code. Any help would be great. Thanks...

Comment: You can replace $\left\lceil\dfrac nm\right\rceil$ by $k$.

Comment: @MicahWindsor Yes, But the question will still remain the same. That's just different notation right? I can also write it as $$S(n) = k + S(k)$$ where k = ceil(n/m), but it's still not the $n*(n+1)/2$ kinda "formula" that I'd like (though, I don't know if it is possible, as it should be evident from the question)

Comment: If you define $d$ to be the digit sum of $n$ in base $m$, $q$ to be the highest power of $m$ dividing $n$, and $p=\lceil \log_m(n)\rceil$ to be the highest power of $m$ in the base $m$ expansion of $n$, then I think your sum has the formula $p-q + (n-d)/(m-1)$.  Is this the sort of thing you were looking for?